# Querying Parent Model with respect to current user's Child Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Accordingly to devise documentation, related records to current_user is always available, despite what I've read previously. For instance: `current_user.comments` `current_user.profile_images`

What bugs me really is this:

Post.rb

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord

    belongs_to :user

    has_many :postsettings, inverse_of: :post

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :postsettings
```

User.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

has_many :posts
has_many :postsettings
```

Postsettings.rb

```
class Postsetting < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :post, required: false
    belongs_to :user, required: false
```

In Posts controller I have this:

```
@post_delete = current_user.postsettings.includes(:postsettings).where.not
(postsettings: {user_id: current_user.id, delete_post: false})
```

Which works, but is not producing the desired outcome because I need to query ALL Posts where current_user.POSTSETTINGS.delete_post is true or false.

So I've been at this for a couple of days now, and I managed to come up with this:

```
@post_delete = Post.includes(current_user.postsettings).where(
postsettings: {user_id: current_user.id, delete_post: false})
```

This produces an error message which I have not seen before.

```
 ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError in Posts#index
#<Postindex id: 284, read: nil, 
created_at: "2017-04-15 11:38:02", 
updated_at: "2017-04-15 11:38:02", post_id: 96, user_id: 1,
delete_post: false>
```

Which indicates as far as I can see that the query finds all that it needs to find. But it won't actually function. Please help me.... I'm dying over here.

Comment: Can you post your user and postsettings models?

Comment: Done, models are added!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer given by max is good, for convenience though, you can set your user model as follows. Add this line to your user model.

```
has_many :posts_with_settings, through: :postsettings, source: :post
```

Now you should be able to call `current_user.posts_with_settings` to give you all the posts with `postsettings` set for `current_user`. From there you can filter as you wish, e.g,

`current_user.posts_with_settings.where(postsettings: {delete_post: true})`

For more info on :through option see [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association).

Comment: Hey redFur, that's a great answer. However, I'm getting" Could not find the association :postsettings in model User" when trying it.

Comment: I actually tried adding the colons. No, the error persists.

Comment: Ohh, I'm sorry, terrible with typos today.. It's actually supposed to be `source: :post` I think. Try again? Edited.

Comment: Yes, you're correct! However, The original problem still persists. Are you suggesting the query to look like this in it's entierty:

    @post_delete = current_user.posts_with_settings.where(postsettings: {delete_post: false})

Or? Because that doesn't take into consideration that I want users to be able to see ALL posts on the platform – And then the users can delete/hide posts as they wish. Now, users only see posts that are created by them.

Comment: Sorry, I am having trouble understanding what exactly you are trying to do. What exactly should setting `delete_post: true` do? Does it indicate whether a user has a right to delete a post?  If you simply want to delete a post just do smth like `Post.find(params[:id]).destroy` in the post controller. The original question, I thought, was about querying for posts which have a `postsetting` for `current_user`.

Comment: Sorry for being abundantly unclear. What I'm trying to do is Mimic deletion of a post. So: User-A creates a Post. Everyone on the site sees it, but Users can individually choose to "delete" or Hide posts they don't like or don't want (and it must be persistent). But all other users who haven't marked the post as deleted, will still see the post/posts as normal.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141784/discussion-between-redfur-and-crashtor).

Answer (score 3):

```
Post.joins(:postsettings)
    .where(postsettings: { user: current_user } )
    .where(postsettings: { delete_post: [true, false] })
```

`.joins` creates a `INNER JOIN` which means that only rows from `posts` with matches in `postsettings` will be returned.

Comment: "Accordingly to devise documentation, related records to current_user is always available, despite what I've read previously." - I have no idea what you really mean by this. Devise is an authentication system and has nothing to do with how you can join related model from your user model. What you're looking for is authorization - not authentication.

Comment: To be clear Devise does not join any associated models when you use the `current_user` helper method. What ever you read is false or you are misinterpreting it.

Comment: I see. Thanks for pointing that out. However, I'm not getting this to work –  It doesn't remove the Post if I mark it as delete_post: true...

Comment: Dude what? Can you edit your question to actually coherently state what you are actually trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm sorry. I thought it was obvious if a Post has postsettings with a column of post_delete on it that it's purpose was to mimic a deletion of the Post. I will edit the question.

Comment: In your question you are asking for "I need to query ALL Posts where current_user.POSTSETTINGS.delete_post is true or false." which is what the above does. If you only want the ones where it is not true than change `delete_post: [true, false]` to `delete_post: false`. But you shoud ensure that  `delete_post` defaults to false so that you don't have null values.

Comment: Yes, the postsettings are created together with Post on Post creation as nested_attributes, so I have set it to false by default. However, I'm still not able to hide a post if I mark a Postsetting belonging to user as True.

Comment: I'm talking about setting a database default for the column. You're asking about like five different thing and then just saying `it does'nt work`. Which is not a problem statement. It makes it pretty much impossible to help you. I would recommend you take a few steps backs - look at your setup and then ask about a specific problem.